# Question about DOMS

Tags: doms

I started going to the gym a few days ago. I felt soreness after my first workout and I did some research and found out that the soreness is a process that is needed for muscle to build/grow.i.e anytime I feel sore, Muscles are breaking down and rebuilding stronger ones. That's what I could get from my research.

Now, it's been maybe 6 days after I started going to the gym. I don't feel the soreness anymore. I've been going to the gym everyday (15 mins hiit on rest days) and lifting heavier than what I started with and yet, I don't feel any soreness.

Why is this happening? Is this normal or is my body already adapting to my workout routine?

Please note: a few weeks back, I went to the gym for about 5 days then I stopped because of a drastic change at my work place. I wasn't feeling anything at that time too after about 3 days.

Comment: Could it be because I do cardio after I'm done with weight lifting?

Comment: There are three stimuli of muscle growth, only one of which is associated with DOMS. Mechanical Tension, Metabolic Stress, and Muscle Damage.